# Problem about absolute continuity of a function

Tags: measure-theory, problem-solving

$f:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ is an increasing function with $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f=0$ ,$\lim_{x\to \infty}f=1$,
and $\int_{R}f'=1$. Prove that $f$ is absolutely continuous on every interval $[a,b]$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $f$ is merely integrable, there is no guarantee that $f'$ exists almost everywhere. And even both existence and integrability of $f'$ given, we are still unable to deduce the absolute continuity of $f$.

Comment: I do no know any integrable function $f$ satisfying your two limit conditions.

Comment: I am sorry, it was a misprint that the function should be integrable, what we have is that the function is increasing.

Comment: I'd have edited this to say $\lim_{x\to-\infty}$ instead of $lim_{x\to-\infty}$, and $[a,b]$ instead of [a,b$, but the "edit" button isn't there.  Why not?

Comment: And now it's appeared.

Comment: @Michael: There was an edit suggested at 2:03 UTC waiting for review (it was approved at 2:39) see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1927) (you can get there by clicking on "edited xx time ago" and then clicking on "suggested xx time ago" - the precise times can be seen by hovering your mouse over xx time ago and waiting until a tool-tip containing the exact time appears). There can only be one suggested edit per question and your first comment is from 02:26 UTC, so you couldn't suggest a second edit until after 02:39 when the first suggestion was approved by Qiaochu.

Answer (score 1):

Because $f$ is increasing, it is differentiable a.e., its derivative is measurable, and $\int_a^b f'\leq f(b)-f(a)$ for all $a<b$ (e.g., see [Wheeden and Zygmund](http://books.google.com/books?id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA111#v=onepage&q&f=false)).  If $f$ is not absolutely continuous on every bounded interval, then there exists $a<b$ such that the inequality is strict for this $a$ and $b$, i.e., $\int_a^b f'<f(b)-f(a)$ (this follows from the characterization of AC functions as integrals of their derivatives, as seen e.g. [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions)).  Let $c=(f(b)-f(a)) - \int_a^b f' >0$.

Now you can show that for all $M>\max\{|a|,|b|\}$, $\int\limits_{-M}^Mf'\leq 1-c$, by breaking it up into 3 parts and applying the results of the previous paragraph along with the fact that $0\leq f\leq 1$.  Once you have this, the proof by contraposition is almost complete.